# Azure ASE AutoScale is slow

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Seems like although, [auto-scaling is possible in an ASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/using-an-ase#how-scale-works) however it needs to have resources provisioned first which is extremely slow (e.g. For Scale Out : 1 hr per worker, For Scale UP : # of workers x 1 hr). This makes auto-scale an almost non-viable option.

Is there something that I am missing or is there a way to this faster ?

Here the motivation to auto-scale is cost and hence using the auto-scale feature when the resources are already provisioned (and are being paid) for isn't feasible.

Comment: I agree I have found it painful that I wish I hadn't decided to use ASE. I am currently looking for an alternative hosting option unless this is resolved. It is disappointing as I have not had such a poor azure experience when it comes to scaling before.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking question! To elaborate on this. Yes, you are correct ASE support autoscaling. You may autoscale individual worker pools based on metrics or on schedule. Also, you can configure an autoscale profile and set limits on your scale. Once you have defined a profile, you can add autoscale rules to scale up or down the number of instances in the worker pool within the bounds defined by the profile.

You may refer to below link might be helpful:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/app-service-environment-auto-scale

Comment: When will the scaling issue be resolved? When you want to scale for demand we have to come to think of this in the terms of minutes not hours.

Would adding a scaling rule mean that the resources are available and ready to use because expected demand is known?